# Getting error List object is not callable on this Caesar cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
plaintext =[
        "this is a test",
        "caesar’s wife must be above suspicion",
        "as shatner would say: you, should, also, be, able, to, handle, punctuation.",
        "to mimic chris walken: 3, 2, 1, why must you, pause, in strange places?",]

shift = 3
def caesar(plaintext):


    alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
    "m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]


    dic={}
    for i in range(0,len
                       (alphabet)):
        dic[alphabet[i]]=alphabet[(i+shift)%len(alphabet)]


    ciphertext=""
    for l in plaintext():
        if l in dic:
            l=dic[l]
        ciphertext+=l

    return ciphertext



print [caesar(plaintext)]
```

I'm not sure why it giving me that error. I need some assistance. I tried putting brackets around and replacing the parathesis, but it still giving that error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/iii/Desktop/y.py", line 33, in <module>
    print (caesar(plaintext))
  File "C:/Users/iii/Desktop/y.py", line 24, in caesar
    for l in plaintext():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: First of all, `print(caesar(plaintext))` is how to print in Python 3.x

Comment: Doesn't change the fact it still giving that same error

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: for l in plaintext():???  plaintext is a list.. just replace with plaintext.

Comment: That'll just print the plaintext as output

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, `print(caesar(plaintext))` is how to print in Python 3.x.
2. You also cannot iterate through a list without calling `len()` on it: `for l in range(len(plaintext)):`
3. You also cannot increment a string, so I suggest if you really want to add 1 to the variable `ciphertext`, make it a number: `ciphertext=0`

This modified code runs without error, as long as it still is what you wanted, I cannot really tell if it is.

```
plaintext =[
        "this is a test",
        "caesar’s wife must be above suspicion",
        "as shatner would say: you, should, also, be, able, to, handle, punctuation.",
        "to mimic chris walken: 3, 2, 1, why must you, pause, in strange places?",]

shift = 3
def caesar(plaintext):
    alphabet=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
    "m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

    dic={}
    for i in range(0,len(alphabet)):
        dic[alphabet[i]]=alphabet[(i+shift)%len(alphabet)]

    ciphertext=0
    for l in range(len(plaintext)):
        if l in dic:
            l=dic[l]
        ciphertext+=l

    return ciphertext

print(caesar(plaintext))
```

***EDIT***

If you want to make a Caesar cipher, [this web site](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html) does a great job of explaining how to make it in Python.

Comment: It should change my plaintext into ciphertext. The changes made the output return an int

Comment: Correct, but your code won't do that anyway. I do not see anywhere where you attempt to add a character to the output string.